# Ionic : ng-click list call-log then show detail log

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

So I have call-logs just showing name and date. 
And now I want to showing Details of that log (number,duration and type of call) its mean that I should click one of call-log list. BUT the problem is I don't have an ID to get Details of that log, because the Data of call-logs live from my handphone.

Is somebody know how to get Details with my problem? or someone have an opinion from my problem? 
Tell me~

Thanks :)

--
Firstly when I click call log menu it show the detail, but now my boss want to separate the Details so here my code before :

Here's my HTML code of call logs

```
<ion-view class="h6" title="Debug" ng-controller="DebugCtrl">
<ion-content class="has-header">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item item-divider">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone"></i> Last Call
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="lcall in data.lastCall">
    <div class="list" style="font-family:calibri;">
        <div class="row" style="font-family:calibri;">
            <div class="col col-30 col-offset-10">Name</div>
            <div class="col">{{lcall.cachedName}}</div>
        </div><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-30 col-offset-10">Number</div>
            <div class="col">{{lcall.number}}</div>
        </div><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-30 col-offset-10">Type</div>
            <div class="col">{{callTypeDisplay(lcall.type)}}</div>
        </div><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-30 col-offset-10">Date</div>
            <div class="col">{{lcall.date | date}} {{lcall.date | date : 'HH:mm'}} <!-- {{data.lastCall.date}} --></div>
        </div><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-30 col-offset-10">Duration</div>
            <div class="col">{{lcall.duration}} seconds</div>
        </div><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-30 col-offset-10">Acknowledged</div>
            <div class="col">{{(lcall.new == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no')}}</div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

and Here's my controllers code of call-logs

```
.controller('DebugCtrl', ['$scope', 'CallLogService', '$timeout', '$ionicLoading','$state',function ($scope, CallLogService, $timeout, $ionicLoading,$state) {
$scope.showLoading = function(){
  $ionicLoading.show({
    content: 'Loading',
    animation: 'fade-in',
    showBackdrop: true,
    maxWidth: 200,
    showDelay: 0
  });

  $timeout(function () {
  //Loading di sembunyikan
  $ionicLoading.hide();
  //Buat di looping coeg
  $state.go('tab.log');
  $scope.data = {};
    console.log('data : ' , $scope.data);
    $scope.callTypeDisplay = function(type) {
      switch(type) {
        case 1:
          return 'Incoming';
        case 2:
          return 'Outgoing';
        case 3:
          return 'Missed';
        default:
          return 'Unknown';
      }
    };
    CallLogService.list(1000).then(
    function(callLog) {
        console.log(callLog);
        //alert('no of call: ',$scope.data.lastCall.length);
        $scope.data.lastCall = callLog;
    },
    function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
  }, 2000);
};}])
```

Comment: can you post a sample of your code?

Comment: are you using ng-repeat to display the call logs?

Comment: @PrinceG yes I use ng-repeat you can see the code in answer colomn

Answer (score 0):

To address your problem where there is no ID to identify which call log is clicked, there is a `$index` property being exposed by ng-repeat. 
$index is an iterator offset of the repeated element.

You can pass `$index` into one of your controller method.

e.g.

`<div ng-repeat="lcall in data.lastCall">
    <div ng-click="controllerFunc($index)">some call log data here</div>
</div>`

Comment: oh I see~ okeoke thanks @PriceG I will try it now ;)